# Query for If search value equals both rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code pretty much like a search engine within the database for peoples names.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $keyword = $_POST['stats'];   
      $orderby = $_POST['orderby'];

      if (!empty($_POST['stats'])) {
          $getStats = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE
              `lastname` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR `firstname` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR
              `nickname` LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY `$orderby`
              DESC");
```

This then prints the results back into a table, I thought the table code wasn't necessary and too long.

The above query works for if I search just the last name or just the first name, or nickname

but if there is for example a user in the database with the name, John Smith
so

> Firstname: John
>     Lastname: Smith

If just searched 'John' he would be printed into the table, which is good and same if I just searched 'Smith'

But if I search 'John Smith' he would not be printed into the table.

How can I change this query so that this will happen, I have tried this:

```
$getStats = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE
    `firstname`, `lastname` = '$keyword' OR `lastname` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR `firstname` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR
    `nickname` LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY `$orderby`
    DESC");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) LIKE %$keyword%`

Also you should be binding parameters rather than directly interpolating user input into the query string, your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$keyword = str_replace(" ", "%", $keyword);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try REGEXP:

```
$keyword = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['stats']); // escape data
$orderby = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['orderby']); // escape data
$keyword = implode("|", explode(" ", $keyword));

$getStats = $db->query("SELECT * FROM stats 
                        WHERE firstname REGEXP '$keyword' 
                           OR lastname REGEXP '$keyword' 
                           OR nickname REGEXP '$keyword' 
                        ORDER BY $orderby DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $sql = "SELECT *
  FROM stats
  WHERE 
  firstname LIKE '%$keyword%'
  OR lastname LIKE '%$keyword%'
  OR CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,lastname,) LIKE '%$keyword%'
  OR CONCAT_WS(' ',lastname,firstname) LIKE '%$keyword%'
  OR nickname LIKE '%$keyword%'
  ORDER BY $orderby DESC";
```